# giving color of path in google directions api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

here is my code to show path

```
function calcRoute() {
  var request = {
          origin: "Chicago, IL",
          destination: "Los Angeles, CA",
          waypoints: [
            {
              location:"Joplin, MO",
              stopover:false
            },{
              location:"Oklahoma City, OK",
              stopover:true
            }],
          provideRouteAlternatives: false,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
        };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

How to change the path color the default is blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this in the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)

The `DirectionsRendererOptions` object takes a `polylineOptions` property where you can define its style.

For example:

```
var directionsOptions = {
    polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor: 'red'
    }
}

directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(directionsOptions);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you add a **polyline** to a Map you can simply use a `PolylineOptions` object, calling the `width()` and `color()` methods on it:

```
    private GoogleMap map;

    //get the map reference from the layout

    //Set the polyline configurations
    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(Color.RED);

    //add the points to the polyline
    rectLine.add(new LatLng(40.3, 18.6));
    rectLine.add(new LatLng(40.3, 20));

    //add the polyline to the map
    map.addPolyline(rectLine);
```